# How to add custom header and bearer token for HttpRequest in Mock Test for Azure Function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am writing Unit Test for Function App which accept HttpRequest and run the secured api call with query parameters and some custom Headers and Bearer Token. I able to pass the query to request But how to add Headers is not working.

I have tried the following code, edited my code as per suggestion of @Nkosi

```
var postParam = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();
postParam.Add("param1", "123");
request.Query = new QueryCollection(postParam);

var headers = new HttpClient().DefaultRequestHeaders;
headers.Add("Transaction", "1234");
var request = Mock.Of<HttpRequest>(_ =>
            _.Query == query && _.Headers == headers //<-- setup desired members
        );
var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger>();

var response = azureFunction.Run(request, logger);
```

Calling the following function

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log){
}
```

I am getting error here operater == can not be applied to IHeaderDictionary and HttpRequestHeaders

```
&& _.Headers == headers
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since using [Linq-to-Mocks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#linq-to-mocks), the setup will need to be done differently

```
//Arrange
var postParam = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();
postParam.Add("param1", "123");
var query = new QueryCollection(postParam);

var headers = new HttpRequestHeaders();
headers.Add("Transaction", "1234");

var request = Mock.Of<HttpRequest>(_ => 
    _.Query == query && _.Headers == headers //<-- setup desired members
);
var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger>();

//Act
var response = azureFunction.Run(request, logger);

//...
```

You could also mock the `IHeaderDictionary` instead

```
//Arrange
var postParam = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();
postParam.Add("param1", "123");
var query = new QueryCollection(postParam);

//mock header dictionary
var headers = Mock.Of<IHeaderDictionary>(_ =>
    _["Transaction"] == "1234"
);

var request = Mock.Of<HttpRequest>(_ => 
    _.Query == query && _.Headers == headers //<-- setup desired members
);
var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger>();
```

Comment: var headers = new HttpRequestHeaders(); we can not instantiate HttpRequestHeader like that, its give error that, HttpRequestHeader does not contain a constructer that take 0 argument

Comment: we can create instance like that  var headers = new HttpClient().DefaultRequestHeaders;  but then we get error on mock object <br/> && _.Headers == headers  operater == can not be applied to IHeaderDictionary and HttpRequestHeaders

Comment: @HasanAbrar You are using the wrong version. The docs says the constructor is public https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.internal.http.httprequestheaders?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi by installing nu-get package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core and referencing  HttpRequestHeaders to using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http it worked